# Python noob: Creating D&D style characters for a game

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

Good day to anyone who is willing to help this Python newbie...

I have been working through Zed Shaw's LPTHW book which has been going well. I'm in Exercise 45 where we need to make a new game using classes. As a part of this, I'm trying to figure out the best way to develop some D&D style characters in the game. Characters would have things like hit points, armor class, a weapon that does X amount of damage, has a basic inventory, etc.

Doing some additional research, I've considered the following two options.

1.. CSV file use -- This exercise wants us to do a file import and I thought doing a CSV file import would be a solid way to organize the data, import/manipulate it in Python, etc. However, while it appears pretty straight forward  on how to import a CSV file into Python, it seems difficult to work with individual fields within the data once the file is read. For example, if the initial player data is brought in from the CSV, it seems difficult to adjust the hit points in that field if the player took damage. (or if an enemy takes damage)

2.. class Character(object) -- In light of #1, I've considered creating this class that defines the different parts of the characters as strings/integers to be defined later as an instance of the class. (ie goblin = Character(x, y, z, etc)  If this option is better, I am additionally curious how to format an initial empty inventory list for someone like the player who would start with nothing in their inventory.

QUESTION: Should I just stick with class use or is what I'm trying to do worth my desire to push myself to try working with import files like a CSV, etc?

I apologize if any of this is confusing. I'm really enjoying my Python studies thus far but this is my first post so it's entirely possible I'm not following good etiquette.

Thanks much!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to be more specific - what exactly are you asking?
Regarding a data format for initial data - many formats could be used; I might've gone with yaml in this case, but I guess json, xml and many others could also be used.

Comment: This question is very broad and opinionated, and is thus off-topic for stackoverflow. Also, "best" is generally a term that doesn't work in programming, as you have so many different things that are best: performance, memory, easiness, maintenance, modularity, cross-platform, etc.. I'd recommend starting with a simple class and expand when you know more about exactly how you're game works internally.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Either option would use classes, it's just that when you're working with CVS-files (or JSON) you're creating instances of the class from the data of the files. So start with the classes and then you should be able to instantiate them from CSV-files later.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Ah, the "creating instances of the class from the data" is where I hit a wall in my research. It seems I need to do a bit more research on how to properly code the connection from the import file to my character class.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with Python classes, because then you can use properties that have sensible names that can be useful for the scope of a game.

```py
class Character:
    '''
    This represents a D&D character with a bunch of stats.
    '''
    # You can use a constructor to initialize a new character
    # with default values for their desired properties
    def __init__(self, health = 10, inventory = None, ...):
        self.health = health
        if inventory is None:
            self.inventory = []
        else:
            self.inventory = inventory
        ...
    # You can add methods for game logic
    def attack(self, other):
        ...
        other.health -= self.damage
    ...
```

Using properties in a class allows you to extract and manipulate relevant information quickly and clearly. Methods help you to control what part of the program should act and how.

Comment: Please try to follow Python's [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) conventions of using `snake_case` as names for methods and attributes. These conventions are meant to improve readability and consistency.